# How do I move a checked item to a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on a checklist program and I want to move the newly checked item of a `CheckedListBox` to a normal `ListBox`, but the item in the `CheckedListBox` doesn't get destroyed and it only adds the text to the normal `ListBox` when you uncheck the item again.

I have already tried to use a `foreach` statement to get all checked items in the `CheckedListBox`.

```
private void TaskBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if(taskBox.CheckedItems != null)
    {
        foreach (object itemChecked in taskBox.CheckedItems)
        {
            string s = taskBox.GetItemCheckState(taskBox.Items.IndexOf(itemChecked)).ToString();
            fTaskBox.Items.Add(s);
            taskBox.Items.Remove(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should get into the habit of using both google and [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.remove?view=netframework-4.8) - Aslo: Why on earth do you turn the index to a string?? It could be used to remove the item with RemoveAt. And why so you add the index and not the item text??

Comment: for your info: i used google and msdn.I looked up the problem on multible websites but every solution had the same problem: it only removed the item when it was  checked and then unchecked again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `ItemCheck` event on `CheckedListBox` fires *before* the item's `CheckState` is actually changed.  That means the just-clicked item has not been added to the `CheckedItems` list yet when you are looping over it.  It works on the second click because the item you checked on the first click is in the `CheckedItems` list by that point and gets picked up in the loop.

One easy way to work around the problem is to use the `MouseUp` event instead.  If you loop over the `CheckedIndices` instead of `CheckedItems` you don't need the extra code to try to figure out the index of the checked item.  This should do it:

```
private void TaskBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (int index in taskBox.CheckedIndices)
    {
        fTaskBox.Items.Add(taskBox.Items[index]);
        taskBox.Items.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```